# HTML files as attachments being manipulated (Python/smtplib)?

Tags: python, html-email, email-attachments, smtplib

###### Python 3.9.7 / Microsoft Office 365 Exchange Online

My application uses `email.message` to create email messages and `smtplib` to send them.  It uses an SMTP server (M365 Exchange Online) on my company's domain to send mail.

Scenario:  My application sends an email from my company's domain (company.com) to two recipients:  (1) me@company.com and (2) me@outlook.com.

- The email has an HTML file (a report) as an attachment.
- For recipient me@outlook.com:

  - The HTML file received opens successfully in a (any) web browser.
  - The HTML file received is 3.45MB.
- For recipient me@company.com:

  - The HTML file received opens as a blank page in a (any) web browser.
  - The HTML file received is 3.00MB.
- The two HTML files (obviously) do not have the same SHA256 checksum.
- All other file types sent as attachments are the same size and SHA256 checksum between the two recipients.

I have tried changing the encoding of the file from `text/html` to `text/plain` and `application/octet-stream`.  No change in results.

Relevant code:

```
fsubtype = ftype.split('/')[1]
ftype = ftype.split('/')[0]
with open(file, mode='rb') as fh:
    content = fh.read()
    msg.add_attachment(content, maintype=ftype, subtype=fsubtype, filename=fname)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, what does `ftype` and `fsubtype` give you when you print them?

Comment: What's the actual problem here? Are you wondering why the HTML file is different when sent to me@company.com, and how to stop that? I've found that if I send such a file zipped, that will bypass any changing of HTML files.

Comment: @gmdev from the application's log, here's what I get:  [2021-10-04 17:13.38] DEBUG: [·] File type: text  Subtype: html

Comment: @Nathan I can see your confusion -- looks like SO changed the title of my question to something that has nothing to do with my actual question.  I've edited it for clarity.  I'm trying to figure out why my HTML files are being manipulated and how to get them to come through correctly.